# EKS Connector Pods stuck in Init:CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have a single node kubernetes cluster setup on AWS,I am currently running a VPC with one public and private subnet.
The master node is in the public subnet and worker node is in the private subnet.

So on the AWS console I can succesfuly register a cluster and download the connector manifest which, I then download and apply the manifest on my master node but unfortunately the pods don't start. the below is what i observered.

kubectl get pods

NAME               READY      STATUS              RESTARTS            AGE
eks-connector-0    0/2  Init:CrashLoopBackOff     7 (4m36s ago)       19m

kubectl logs ejs-connector-0

Defaulted container "connector-agent" out of: connector-agent, connector-proxy, connector-init (init)
Error from server (BadRequest): container "connector-agent" in pod "eks-connector-0" is waiting to start: PodInitializing

The pods are failing to start with th above logged errors.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest providing output of `kubectl get pod eks-connector-0 -o yaml` and `kubectl logs -p eks-connector-0`